# Why git branch doesn't display anything?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am working on a repository with github.
When I execute `git branch`, there isn't anything displaied on my screen (see picture bellow).

[git branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSuY3.png)

When I execute `git status`, it is said I'm in a branch.

[git status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsldu.png)

So there is some branches and I am working with them.
Do you know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: `git branch --list` does the same?

Comment: Does `git log` show commits?

Comment: What is your OS and your shell ?

Comment: `` git branch --list`` do the same @DaemonPainter

Comment: ``git log`` show my commit @TTT

Comment: I am using Windows 10 (18363.1198), on windows shell. 
I am using anaconda prompt (anaconda3). @LeGEC

Comment: Strange... can you see the branches listed in the directory: .git\refs\heads\ ?

Comment: Please put the output of your commands into the question rather than linking to images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git branch` runs its list of branches through your chosen *pager*.  If there is something wrong with the pager setup, this could "eat" the output, producing the result you see.  If `git --no-pager branch` works correctly, this is the problem.

The solution is to fix your pager.  First, figure out which pager you chose: run `git var GIT_PAGER`.  The output is the pager you chose.  This could come from:

- The environment variable `GIT_PAGER`: if this is set, this is your pager.
- Your configuration, i.e., `git config --get core.pager`: if this is set, this is your default pager.
- The value built into Git.  If neither `GIT_PAGER` nor `core.pager` are set, this is what Git will use.

The goal of this pager is to keep the output from a long-output-command from scrolling away off your screen / out of the recall range of your window.  (Even with, e.g., 10,000 recall lines in a window, some commands can produce more output than that.)  A bad pager setting is no fun but a good one can be very helpful, so figure out which pager(s) you like and how to use them, and configure your Git setup to use the pager you like best.

Comment: thanks for your help, I fix this problem with the command ``git config --global core.pager cat``

Comment: Note that with the `cat` setting, you get the effect of having no pager at all. This can be inconvenient so you might want to investigate using a real pager like `less` (there's a learning curve for these though).

Comment: so strange, was having this problem on OS X, but not Linux with the same config. I'm setting my to `bat --style=plain`, which is the same as cat except it will page. `bat`++ ;)