# Anaconda/Git: git branch command is silent despite it working in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: git, anaconda3

Every time I try to run any variation of the command "git branch" (git branch -vv or git branch -a), none of them work. I receive a blank line back as indicated in Fig. 1.

The common suggestion is to make a commit to the repo. I've done that and it still isn't working.

Another common suggestion is to do: "git remote prune origin". That hasn't helped either.

I then reinstalled git using: "conda install -c anaconda git". No changes. Also, I have the GIT GUI installed if that indicates anything (I doubt it does).

If it's of interest, my Anaconda prompt flashes each time I run "git branch" but not when I run other commands (almost like it is reoutputing the prompt or something, idk really know).

Let me show you what I have as git output:

[Fig. 1: Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIVnP.png)

Anaconda is kind of a black box for me. I've not super familiar with it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566292/7976758

Comment: For some reason, anaconda setups always seem to have broken pagers. Admittedly I only poked at anaconda once or twice, so I'm generalizing from too-few examples...

Comment: phd's comment above is very helpful. It answered my questions. Also, thank you torek for your comment. I couldn't find this for the life of me. I was drowning in answers about not committing that I couldn't find anything on broken pagers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem can be found in this Stack Overflow thread: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564804/why-git-branch-doesnt-display-anything/65566292#65566292). Thank you phd.